# How to set system fonts for Japanese language?

Tags: swift, xcode, fonts, storyboard

Now I'm using Storyboard,  and making a view with a button on it, that says "次へ"which means next, and with an underline and the link to next page.

I want to set the font of this Japanese character"次へ"to system font but it always says "Hiragino Kaku Gothic Interface W3"on Storyboard.

If I set the title to plain, I can set the font to system font, however, when set attributed, there's no selection for system font.

Does anybody know how to fix this and have a button with an underlined character , system font and saying "次へ"？

I'd appreciate your kindness. Thank you.

Comment: If you want the system font, you have to do it in code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've decided to  do it in code and it worked. Appreciate for your help.